# Making a software lock for a web project

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-2.2

How to create a software lock on a asp.net core(aspnetboilerplate) project?
I want to know how many active versions of my project on the Internet are there?
And I can disable some of them.

Comment: No one has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not a simple enough task to provide actual code samples, but on a high level, you could achieve this by tracking IP sessions in DB. If you're solely looking to only allow a set number of active sessions entirely, then you would just check the IP sessions database to see if you've met your quota or not and then either allow or deny the next session based on that check. To extend that to allowing a super admin to kill sessions, you could just check that the user has a record in the DB meaning there is a valid session, and you would delete the record to "kill" the session.

If you're looking to only allow 1 session per user, then on login, save a record for the users current IP address and their UserId. Overwrite or create a new record for this, then on a periodic user session isAuthenticated check, you would verify that the users current Ip matches the record in the table. If it matches it would be the user that logged in, if it doesn't match then another IP address is using that login and you would kill their session.

Comment: No one has an idea?

Comment: I provided an 'idea' above